# How to prevent two labels created in run-time from intersecting with each other? (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, label

I have a canvas, which, upon a click on the left button of the mouse, has a label created on it in the clicking point. This is the xaml code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int num = 1;
    List <Label> countries = new List<Label>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var point = Mouse.GetPosition(Canvas);
        Label label = new Label() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
                    Canvas.Children.Add(label);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(label, point.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(label, point.Y);
                    label.Focus();
                    num++;
                    countries.Add(label);
            }
    }
```

I would like to make it so two different labels would not be able to intersect with each other. The idea is that if the user tries to create a label in a location which would cause it to intersect with another existing label, a message box would pop and tell him to choose another location.

Unfortunately I did not succeed in implementing this. If anyone could help, I would be very glad.
Help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
 private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var point = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
            Rect newrect = new Rect(point.X, point.Y, 100, 100);
            Boolean isIntersects = false;
            foreach (Control control in canvas.Children)
            {
                if (control is Label)
                {
                    Rect oldrect = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(control), Canvas.GetTop(control), control.Width, control.Height);
                    if (newrect.IntersectsWith(oldrect))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Oops. Intersecting...");
                        isIntersects = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isIntersects == false)
            {
                Label label = new Label() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
                label.Content = "This is a label:)";
                label.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                canvas.Children.Add(label);
                Canvas.SetLeft(label, point.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(label, point.Y);
            }
        }
```